# Facebook PHP SDK 4.0 - Handling denied permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

When a user clicks 'Cancel' when being asked for permissions, it would generate a $_GET parameter

```
facebook_registration.php?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied&state=a2101ba3af0381cf82db6120319cad25#_=_
```

My question is what is the proper way of handling this type of error?
The only way I see is by reading the $_GET parameter like this

```
<?php
     if(isset($_GET['error']))
     {
          //handle it here
     }
?>
```

I was under the impression that Facebook had a better way of handling this, but after searching through the documentation and Google, I might've been mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the querystring as you already outlined. There are some suggestions on how to handle this in the docs:

- Last paragraph: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1#login
- Handling missing permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#handling
- Checking permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#adding
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1#re-asking-declined-permissions